# How to Setup Armeria With Bazel?

Tags: armeria

I'm new to Bazel and Armeria. In the Armeria dev guide, in setting up with a build system, it has examples from Gradle and Maven, but not Bazel. Downloading the jar file (armeria-1.18.0.jar) and importing it directly using java_import() will build the project, but gives and error during runtime. It cannot find the runtime dependencies of Armeria like micrometer, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems more like a question about bazel rather than armeria.
Have you tried using `maven_install`? I guess this takes care of pulling in transitive dependencies.

- Sample: https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/main/java-maven
- Documentation: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external